# Como arrumar uma pergunta?

Tags: suporte, perguntas

Já aconteceu comigo de, por falta de conhecimento no assunto, fazer uma pergunta sobre algo e, depois de alguns comentário ou até mesmo respostas, descobrir que a pergunta foi feita erroneamente.

Por exemplo, [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316969/o-que-%C3%A9-o-status-http-220/317055#317055) sobre o status http 220, depois de um comentário e resposta descobri que a  a dúvida não era sobre o status http 220 mas sim um status ftp 220

Como comentei depois, não sabia que existia status diferentes para protocolos diferentes, achava que esses valores eram universais (iguais para todos os protocolos)

Como corrigir uma pergunta nesses casos? Ou devo manter como ela foi feita? Sobre a questão de outros usuário procurarem pelo mesmo tema, ao deixar o título e tags errados, não dificultaria buscas do mesmo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Há dois princípios aqui aparentemente em conflito:

1. Erros são comuns e devem ser editados para serem corrigidos.
2. Todo mundo odeia perguntas camaleão.

Deixar do jeito que havia sido postado originalmente (HTTP) no título, tal como as revisões 1, 2, 4 e 6 estão vai de acordo com o princípio 2, mas contra o princípio 1.

Deixar da forma corrigida, tal como as revisões 3 e 5, vai contra o princípio 2, mas de acordo com o princípio 1.

No entanto, isso não é de todo uma pergunta camaleão, que seria o caso de uma pergunta sobre a função `printf` do C sendo substituída por uma outra sobre como verificar login e senha em Python. No caso, é apenas a correção de um erro na pergunta. Pode ser até um erro razoavelmente grave com bastante impacto nas respostas, em especial a do Guilherme Nascimento. Mas isso é apenas a correção de um erro e não vejo sentido em perpetuar-se esse erro.

Bagunças, confusões e lambanças como essa acontecem de vez em quando. Que atire a primeira pedra quem nunca fez algo assim. Na minha opinião, vale o seguinte: Que a pergunta fique correta e que as respostas do sam e do Guilherme Nascimento sejam atualizadas.

No entanto, especialmente considerando-se a resposta do Guilherme Nascimento que seria a mais prejudicada por isso, acho que dá para encontrar uma solução que reduza o impacto disso: **Coloque na pergunta, uma observação dizendo que inicialmente você pensava que o FTP e que o HTTP tinham os mesmos status.** E que nas respostas seja incluído um texto explicativo dizendo que a pergunta inicialmente falava de status HTTP 220, mas que isso era um equívoco que já foi sanado. As mudanças na resposta do sam frente a isso são mínimas. Na resposta do Guilherme Nascimento, uma notinha no começo dizendo que a pergunta originalmente falava de status HTTP 220 ao invés de FTP 220 também deve ser o suficiente para resolver esse problema.

Embora isso seja chato, sempre vai acontecer de vez em quando. E já aconteceu comigo de ter respostas inteiras invalidadas por esse tipo de coisa, mas isso faz parte. **Superada a confusão feita e desfeitos os equívocos, segue-se a vida.**

Há um pequeno agravante aqui, a edição sugerida (revisão 3) do luislhl (que eu votei para aprovar, inclusive) acabou sendo rejeitada por você, e na ausência de um moderador, como você é o autor da postagem, então a sua opinião tem poder de decisão autocrático, afinal a postagem é sua e então você deve saber o que nela deveria ser escrito. O problema aqui é que na revisão 4, você refez as mudanças que o luislhl fez e ele acabou ficando sem os 2 pontinhos que teria pela aprovação da edição sugerida. No entanto, esse equívoco já está consumado e o luislhl terá muitas oportunidades para reconquistar esses 2 pontinhos e muitos outros. E a vida segue.

Comment: O que percebi foi o seguinte, se me lembro bem: a pergunta inicialmente falava em HTTP etc e tal.. houveram algumas edições que mudaram para FTP (tanto no título quanto nas tags) ficando correta a pergunta... como era à noite, todo mundo foi dormir e ficou assim...

Comment: no dia seguinte, logo cedo, o AP reverteu tudo, voltando para HTTP. Por isso tem um comentário meu lá questionando. Bom, enquanto eu redigia uma resposta, apareceu a resposta do Guilherme, aí já era tarde pro AP re-reverter a pergunta. Ai postei a minha resposta. Um tempo depois o AP corrigiu a pergunta, voltando com o FTP no título e nas tags, mas aí já não podia porque já haviam 2 respostas. Foi isso que entendi.

Comment: Ou seja, a pergunta amanheceu certinha, mas por algum motivo o próprio AP reverteu logo cedinho, tipo umas 8 horas da manhã.

Comment: Não sei, não tenho certeza de nada no momento, mas para mim o interessante foi justamente diferenciar o que é HTTP de FTP, tanto que o próprio AP admitiu que acreditava ser tudo a mesma coisa e ali, tanto minha resposta quanto o comentário de alguns outros participantes o orientaram, nisso penso que justamente poderia ser interessante da forma que estava inicialmente, mas não vou me envolver, se acharem melhor editar para 'corrigir' a pergunta simplesmente irei apoiar e não irei para discutir nada mais, inclusive irei remover a resposta e talvez no futuro faça uma nova mais elaborada.

Comment: Dei +1 logo quando li os 2 primeiros pontos, mas dava +1, se pudesses, por "Superada a confusão feita e desfeitos os equívocos, segue-se a vida". É exatamente isso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento concordo que foi mais interessante (pelo menos pra mim) saber que existe uma diferença entre o os status do http e do ftp do que saber o que é o status ftp 220